# How to remove k__BackingField from json when Deserialize

Tags: .net, json, serialization, deserialization

I am getting the k_BackingField in my returned json after serializing a xml file to a .net c# object.

I've added the DataContract and the DataMember attribute to the .net c# object but then I get nothing on the json, client end.

```
[XmlRoot("person")]
[Serializable]
public class LinkedIn
{
    [XmlElement("id")]
    public string ID { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("industry")]
    public string Industry { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("first-name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("last-name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("headline")]
}
```

Example of the returned json:

```
home: Object
<FirstName>k__BackingField: "Storefront"
<LastName>k__BackingField: "Doors"
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Automatic Property syntax is actually not recommended if the class can be used in serialization. Reason being the backing field is generated by compiler which can be different each time code is compiled. This can cause incompatibility issues even if no change is made to the class (just recompiling the code).

I think applying DataMember attribute will fix the issue in this case. But I would recommend to use full property syntax, if the class needs to be used in serialization.

Comment: Lol,implemented the long version and it set the private fields to the client.home: Object
_fName: "Storefront"
_headline: "CEO at StorefrontDoors.NET"
_id: ""
_industry: ""

Comment: adding that datacontract to the top of the class and datamember to each property that i'm interested in worked.

Comment: @AlumCloud.Com +1 for [DataContract] and [DataMember]. Don't forget to add: System.Runtime.Serialization

Answer (score 118):

Remove `[Serializable]` from your class

Comment: Now I am wondering why I thought I needed [Serializable] in the first place. My Xml serialization works without and JSON works without it.

Comment: This doesn't work with WCF Services. When returning a payload using RESTful services this doesn't yield any data if you remove [Serializable].

Add System.Runtime.Serialization and use [DataContract] for class, [DataMember] for properties.

Comment: This answer AND Ian comment seems to cover both cases.  To WCF or not to WCF, that is the question.

Comment: @Rhyous - in Web API you don't need [Serializable], because Web API is set up with the assumption you're going to be serializing and returning your objects (since that's basically the entire idea) - in other C# applications you generally need Serializable to differentiate serializable objects

Comment: Thank you, I was stuck with `[Serializable]`, so adding backing fields helped.

Comment: Hello, It works but i need to keep [Serializable] to my class because i have used same class for my backoffice and i have used  SQL server session . to store this class in session i need to keep [Serializable]. any other solution please ?

Comment: @IanNewland You are right. On removing [Serializable], the WCF service doesn't yield any data. I did add [DataContract] for Class and [DataMember] for properties - but I still see no Data. Can you suggest

Answer (score 66):

The default WebApi serializer will add that "__BackingField:" syntax to c# auto-properties.  Add this to your WebConfig in App_Start to get the cleaner looking json that you might be looking for.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
...

config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
```

Comment: This fixed the problem. I think auto properties are clean. Using backing fields everywhere seem stupid. and introduces a lot of clutter and sometimes confusion.

Comment: This worked for me. In my case, i had an existing class that was already being used by WCF and ASMX webservices, so i could not just change it for my new WebAPI project.

Comment: The question is why on earth WebApi serializer will add that "__BackingField:" by default?

Comment: good solution. in my case, i need to use [Serializable] save into memcache. Serializable is require.

Comment: What would I do without StackOverflow? Thanks.

Comment: The question is - which is better approach - to remove [Serializable] or to use op suggestion, because both seems to work.

Comment: Where to add this code On WCF side ?  ?

Answer (score 40):

We have some objects which are marked as `[Serializable]` so they can be serialised using traditional methods, but which we need to have cleanly serialised in JSON for use with Web API. Setting `IgnoreSerializableAttribute` to `true` will stop Newtonsoft.Json from behaving like Microsoft's serialisers and instead it will just serialise the public properties.

TLDR: Add this to WebApiConfig.cs:

```
((Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver)config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver).IgnoreSerializableAttribute = true;
```

Moderator: Rather than deleting a really good answer to a question that has been asked several times, please delete the duplicate question. This is a valid answer to a valid question.

Comment: This should be the right answer. Removing Serialization or using datacontract and datamember attributes is not always the correct solution.

Comment: Many of us are not, including OP, using Webapi or MVVM or what ever it is you guys  are on about. What is app_start and webapiconfig when I have a normal soap WCF service with service.svc?

Comment: Thanks , this solution works for me.   Its remove k__BackingField  from WEB API response.

Answer (score 14):

**Simple Easy and Decent way to expose data**
We need to expose out data in object to easy readable and consistent format

First remove *[Serializable]*

```
    [Serializable]
```

now add **[DataContract]** in class and **[DataMember]** for property like below example

```
[DataContract]
public class UserDiscretion : UserReport
{
    [DataMember]
    public String DiscretionCode { get; set; }
    public String DiscretionDescription { get; set; }
}
```

Hope this help

Thanks.

Comment: If using Web API, there's no need to add the DataContract and DataMember attributes at all - simply return the object and it will be serialised automatically.

Comment: If anyone starting development from scratch so it will be great to use Web API 

which will provide Object return type will not require any type of type casting to exposing to client.
But for @AlumCloud.com question, if he is in the existing application so solution for his problem will be by 
First remove [Serializable]
then add [DataContract] in class and [DataMember] for property like below as suggested

Comment: This adds a tremendous amount of "noise" to your classes and is essentially unnecessary (see all the other comments). If one feels the need to actually do this, however, I would recommend using something like PostSharp to add the code for you during compilation so that it doesn't clutter up your classes with all of those attributes.

Answer (score 8):

Couple of options:

1. Remove `[Serializable]` from model
2. Add `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]` to your model along with  `[Serializable]`
3. Add below line to `App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs`

```cs
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
```

Answer (score 4):

Another solution that may help in case of JSON.NET. It may be enough to mark class with [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonObject] attribute.

I was working with cs classes built from xsd and was adding some properties using partial classes. After json serialization these properties were marked with k_BackingField. JsonFormatter settings mentioned in other answers helped as well, but more simple was to mark partial class with [JsonObject] attribute.

Answer (score 2):

I was using `DataContractJsonSerializer` with a class from another assembly that had the `Serializable` attribute. The output contained "k__BackingField". Removing the `Serializable` attribute (in the other assembly) fixed this. Not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you see this issue inside of your MVC project, I've found that it's pretty simple to replace the use of @Html.JsonData.  Here is a snippet of code that has worked for me in the past:

```
<input type="hidden" id="Model" value="@Html.Raw(new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model))" />
```

Not as elegant, but simple in a pinch.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when I have self reference properties in my class such as;

```
class Person {
 List<Person> Friends { get; set;}
}
```

And there was a result, the person was friend with himself. I just made sure there was no self referencing objects in my result set. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use the [Serializable] attributes, so removing it was not an option.

[XmlSerializer ignores [XmlAttribute] in WebApi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35846873/xmlserializer-ignores-xmlattribute-in-webapi)

The above resolution solved it for me.

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case this error was for the Newtonsoft.Json Version, the server looked for 6.0.0 version and I had the 11.0, so I had to install the version 6.0.0

Answer (score -2):

Friends, don't declare properties like this:

```
public String DiscretionCode { get; set; }
public String DiscretionDescription { get; set; }
```

But, create auxiliar vars, like old....

```
private String discretionCode;

public String DiscretionCode 
{ 
    get { return discretionCode;}
    set { discretionCode = value; }
}
```

Comment: Why? Could you give a reson?

Comment: @Lucenty it gives a JSON like this.. [{ "discreationCode" :  "x"}], when  serializing.

Comment: But this is what I would expect - this is how JSON serializes data. And I think that the code with auxiliar vars will give the same result.

Comment: k_BackingField  has been added to indicate an auto-property has been serialised. If you refactor the auto-property to a property and a backing field then the problem would go away. I think there's better solutions in this thread but this works.