# Deserialize json array data in c#

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, umbraco

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# automatic property deserialization of JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/945585/c-sharp-automatic-property-deserialization-of-json)

Hi all I am trying to deserialize json Data

```
json Data: {"Status":[{"StatusValue":"Test1","StatusValue1":"Test2","StatusValue2":"Test3","StatusValue3":"Test4"},
{"StatusValue":"Test5","StatusValue1":"Test6","StatusValue2":"Test7","StatusValue3":"Test8"},
{"StatusValue":"Test9","StatusValue1":"Test10","StatusValue2":"Test11","StatusValue3":"Test12"}]}
```

On Server side JSON data coming Fine but I am not able to deserialize it. The code I have written below for deserialize Json Data.

```
  public static T JsonDeserialize<T>(string jsonString)
    {
        DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString));
        T obj = (T)ser.ReadObject(ms);
        return obj;
    }
```

And Class Which I have created Separately :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace CustomDataType
{
    [Serializable]
    [XmlRoot("StatusMain")]
    public class Status
    {
            [XmlElement("statusvalue")]
            public string StatusValue { get; set; }

            [XmlElement("statusvalue1")]
            public string StatusValue1 { get; set; }

            [XmlElement("statusvalue2")]
            public string StatusValue2 { get; set; }

            [XmlElement("statusvalue3")]
            public string StatusValue3 { get; set; }

            public static Status Empty 
            {
                get
                {
                    var schedule = new Status();
                    schedule = null;
                    return schedule;
                }
            }
    }
}
```

**And Class In which I am using: I have write the code like below**

```
        Status test = new Status();
        test = CustomDataTypes.JsonDeserialize<Status>(JsonDataValue);
```

**Error Which I am getting:**
[image]

Comment: Have you tried `DataContract` `DataMember` attributes instead of `XmlElement`, `XmlRoot`?

Comment: Actually I am using xml serialization for keeping data in database. isn't it possible to do in this way ?

Comment: Why dont you use Json.Net. I find it much simpler and faster than DataContractJsonSerializer

Comment: try that[Serializable, DataContract]

Comment: @Nishant then use both attributes.

Comment: @L.B Still getting same error

Comment: Solution is discussed here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13022198/how-to-remove-k-backingfield-from-json-when-deserialize