# XmlSerializer ignores [XmlAttribute] in WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, xmlserializer

I have a WebApi that returns a simple object, but when I'm forcing it to return as XML (`Accept: application/xml`) it ignores the `[XmlAttribute]` attribute I've set on the object.

This is my object:

```
public class Foo
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

And I return it like this in the code:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/mytest")]
public class MyTestController : System.Web.Http.ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("gettest")]
    public Foo GetTest()
    {
        return new Foo() { Bar = "foobar" };
    }
}
```

The resulting XML is:

```
<Foo>
    <Bar>foobar</Bar>
</Foo>
```

Whereas I would expect it to be returned like this:

```
<Foo Bar="foobar">
</Foo>
```

Why does the XmlSerializer used by WebApi ignore the `[XmlAttribute]` attribute, and how can I make it work like I want to?

Comment: What is the type of the "simple object"? I have a feeling your Foo Bar isn't your real code.

Comment: You are right that Foo Bar isn't my real code, but I actually did recreate the issue with what I described in my question, so my real code doesn't matter as Foo Bar also fails.

Answer (score 6):

Try setting this global configuration value in your WebApi to true

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true;
```

By default Web API uses DataContractSerializer in XmlMediaTypeFormatter.

Comment: I have a `HttpConfiguration` configuration object, and I did a `config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true;` on the object being used to start the WebApi. Unfortunately that had no effect.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me... no need to change global configuration.

```
var configuration = new HttpConfiguration();
configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true;
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, myObjectToSerialize, configuration);
```