# Deserializing JSON Object from JsonConvert returns null

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization, json-deserialization

Without serializing getting data from API response

```
var apiResponseDetails = authorityApiResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
"[
    {
        \"<RoleName>k__BackingField\":\"L5 _Admin _Role\",
        \"<RoleType>k__BackingField\":\"565,1\"
    }
]"
```

While Deserializing the same response getting null for `RoleName` and `RoleType`

```
lstRole = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ChangeRoleNotification>>(Convert.ToString(apiResponseDetails));
Name                Value                               
lstRole             Count = 1                           
    [0]             {Presentation.Common.ChangeRoleNotification}    
       RoleName     null                                            
       RoleType     null
```

---

```
[Serializable]
public class ChangeRoleNotification
{
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty(PropertyName = "RoleName")]
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty(PropertyName = "RoleType")]
    public string RoleType { get; set; }
}
...

GetUserRolesDetailsRequest getUserRolesDetails = new GetUserRolesDetailsRequest();
getUserRolesDetails.UserID = objUser.UserId;
getUserRolesDetails.RoleName = HttpContext.Current.Session["UserTypeName"].ToString();
getUserRolesDetails.RoleType = HttpContext.Current.Session["RoleType"].ToString();
getUserRolesDetails.RoleID = Convert.ToInt64(HttpContext.Current.Session["RoleID"]);
    
System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage authorityApiResponse = new System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage(false ? HttpStatusCode.OK : HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
System.Net.Http.HttpContent RequestDetails = new StringContent(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(getUserRolesDetails), Encoding.UTF8);

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(GetWebConfigKeyValueStatic("FrameworkApiURL")))
{
    authorityApiResponse = API.PostAPIAsJson($"{GetWebConfigKeyValueStatic("FrameworkApiURL")}Category/GetCategoryUserRolesDetails", RequestDetails);
    if (authorityApiResponse != null && authorityApiResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK && authorityApiResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result != null)
    {
        var apiResponseDetails = authorityApiResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        lstRole = new List<ChangeRoleNotification>();
        lstRole = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ChangeRoleNotification>>(Convert.ToString(apiResponseDetails));
    }
}
```

Since I am working in converting a project into ASP.NET MVC 3-Tier I see a weird `k__BackingField` what does it mean?

---

**Updated with Server Side Snippet of Response API:**

```
[Route("Category/GetCategoryUserRolesDetails")]
[ActionName("GetCategoryUserRolesDetails")]
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage GetCategoryUserRolesDetails(CategoryRequestDetails categoryRequestDetails)
{
    List<ChangeRoleNotification> response = null;
    FrameworkAPIs.Log.LogClass.log.Debug("\nModule Name : Category;\nMethod Name : GetCategoryUserRolesDetails;\n Message :GetCategoryUserRolesDetails method starts ");
    string statusCode = String.Empty;
    DateTime StartTime = DateTime.Now;
    DateTime EndTime = DateTime.Now;
    Int64 WebServiceLogID = (new ServiceLogGenerator()).GenerateLog(categoryRequestDetails, "Category", "GetCategoryUserRolesDetails", StartTime, EndTime, "", "", null, 0);
    try
    {
        ManageCategory mangageCategory = new ManageCategory();
        if (categoryRequestDetails.UserID > 0)
            response = mangageCategory.GetCategoryUserRolesDetails(categoryRequestDetails);
        else
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Invalid UserID");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        FrameworkAPIs.Log.LogClass.log.Error("\nModule Name : Category;\nMethod Name : GetCategoryUserRolesDetails;\nError Message : " + ex.Message + ex.StackTrace + "\n");
        (new ServiceLogGenerator()).GenerateLog(null, "", "", StartTime, DateTime.Now, ex.StackTrace + ";\n" + ex.Message, "", null, WebServiceLogID);
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex);
    }
    (new ServiceLogGenerator()).GenerateLog(null, "", "", StartTime, DateTime.Now, "", "", response, WebServiceLogID);
    FrameworkAPIs.Log.LogClass.log.Debug("\nModule Name : Category;\nMethod Name : GetCategoryUserRolesDetails;\n Message :GetCategoryUserRolesDetails method ends\nResult :" + response);
    return Request.CreateResponse<List<ChangeRoleNotification>>(HttpStatusCode.OK, response);
}
```

Comment: Where is this weird `k__BackingField` coming from? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41816382/json-serialization-adding-k-backingfield-to-my-properties

Comment: Probably there is something unusual or incorrect on the server side. That _k__BackingField_ seems to be the name assigned to the automatic backing field for [autoimplemented properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8817070/is-it-possible-to-access-backing-fields-behind-auto-implemented-properties). It will be useful to see the code where these objects are serialized

Comment: Please show the type used on the server as the return type from that endpoint, as well as the server code that does the actual serialization.

Comment: Updated the forum post with Server side response implementation @LasseV.Karlsen

Comment: If the `ChangeRoleNotification` on the server is the same as the one you've shown I can't see how that would end up serializing the backing fields. Have you configured json serialization in any way?

Comment: Before posting I have verified thrice. Yes indeed `ChangeRoleNotification` is same in both the ends and for testing I have added  the property as `[Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty(PropertyName = "RoleName")]`. Configuration of Json serialization is left with default.. weird thing with `null` values... @LasseV.Karlsen

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not an appropriate solution because of adding `[JsonObject]` attribute instead of `[Serializable]`. The issue with `k__BackingField` and `null` was solved.
If any one knows exactly how to deal with this by adding `[Serializable]` they are always welcome

```
[Newtonsoft.Json.JsonObject]
public class ChangeRoleNotification
{
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
    public string RoleType { get; set; }
}
```

---

**Updated with below approaches**

**Approach I:** `k__BackingField` vanishes. But `null` seems to persist in server side

```
[Serializable]
public class ChangeRoleNotification
{
    private string RoleNameField;
    public string RoleName
    {
        get { return RoleNameField; }
        set { RoleNameField = value; }
    }
    private string RoleTypeField;
    public string RoleType
    {
        get { return RoleTypeField; }
        set { RoleTypeField = value; }
    }
}
```

**Approach II (Worked):** Both `k__BackingField` and `null` vanishes

```
[Serializable, DataContract]
public class ChangeRoleNotification
{
  [DataMember]
  public string RoleName { get; set; }

  [DataMember]
  public string RoleType { get; set; }
}
```

By adding `[DataContract]` in class and `[DataMember]` for property alone in only server side resolved in Approach II and I believe this one is most appropriate

Comment: For Json serialization you don't need to apply `[Serializable]`, so if this is causing problems, just remove it. That attribute is as far as I know only used by binary serialization, aka `BinaryFormatter`. Have you tried removing all the attributes altogether? You should only need to add extra attributes if you want to change the serialization/deserialization away from the default, but in almost all cases, the default should be OK for this class.

Comment: Yeah! I believe without `[Serializable]` it would still work. In our project they are forced to contract this with every class properties without which they will never accept our work. If you find any implementations difference b/w with or without `[Serializable]` I could possibly raise objection or argue with any implementation part in our project @LasseV.Karlsen

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why the presence of that attribute impacts the serialization of those properties vs. their backing fields. Again, AFAIK that attribute should only be used by BinaryFormatter and binary serialization. So unless someone has made some "clever" tricks regarding Json serialization that also uses this attribute, it shouldn't matter whether you have it or not. I also tested this, both Json.net and System.Text.Json serialized the properties, not the backing fields, as expected.

Comment: My guess would be that there is actually some configuration being done for one of the json serializers, and this is what is causing the issues.

Comment: And if you have lead programmers that dictate that you need to apply Serializable attribute to types that will be json serialized I would encourage you to find a new place to work. Cargo cult programmers are the worst to work with. At the very least stay informed and don't turn into one yourself.