# _x003C__x003E_k__BackingField problem in WCF

Tags: c#, .net, rest, wcf, service

I have created a WCF Service (Ajax-enabled).

With [Serializable] attribute decorated to my class, the output looks as below:

> <_x003C_FirstName_x003E_k__BackingField>ABC</_x003C_FirstName_x003E_k__BackingField>
> <_x003C_HomePhone_x003E_k__BackingField>1234567890</_x003C_HomePhone_x003E_k__BackingField>
> <_x003C_LastName_x003E_k__BackingField>PQR</_x003C_LastName_x003E_k__BackingField>
> <_x003C_MailAddress2_x003E_k__BackingField/>

And by removing the [Serializable] attribute to my class, the output does not render any data as below:

> <FirstName i:nil="true"/<HomePhone i:nil="true"/<LastName i:nil="true"/
> <MailAddress1 i:nil="true"/

Answer (score 0):

There are two options :

1. Add `DataContract` and `DataMember` to your code with `Serializable`.
2. Add the line below to WebApiConfig.cs.

`config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();`

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have tried your first option, and it does not render any data. And I do not have a WebApiConfig.cs in my project.

Comment: Maybe you can refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13022198/how-to-remove-k-backingfield-from-json-when-deserialize) to find some solution.